# Resolvent set of extension

Tags: functional-analysis, spectral-theory

Suppose X is an incomplete normed space and X' is its completion. Let T be a bounded linear operator on T and T' the linear extension of T to X'. How do I prove that the resolvent set p(T) of T coincides with p(T')??